# django docs email is not activated after click on email confirmation link in Django mail backend

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework, django-email

I created the Django email backend for active the email during the registration. But in my case When I register the account and confirmation email is sent on my email and after click on the confirmation link then it's not activate the user's account and link is not redirected on login page.

**setting.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "USERNAME"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_confirm_complete')
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_confirm_complete')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^user_reg/registration/account-email-verification-sent/', email_view.null_view, name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    url(r'^user_reg/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
    url(r'^user_reg/registration/complete/$', email_view.complete_view, name='account_confirm_complete'),
    url(r'^user_reg/password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', email_view.null_view, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user_reg/', include('users.urls', namespace="users")),
    path('user_reg/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**And below the email message**

```
Greeting from example.com!

You're receiving this e-mail because user usertest has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account via API.
To confirm this is correct, go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_reg/registration/account-confirm-email/Mjg:1jSeJC:4btJkSnHSxYN7w5CITEPydcG9cA/

Thank you from example.com!
example.com
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve this?.
Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm no Django expert, but your patterns in *urls.py* start with `user_reg`, while the URL in your email refers to `/user/`, is this intentional or a typo or may it be the cause of your issue?

Comment: It was my mistake in type this question. @amain